# Re-entering Canada after several tourist visa extensions?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, tourist-visas

My mother has been in Canada since January 2020 on a tourist visa. Due to COVID and closed borders, we have been extending her stay by asking for a Visitor Record (so far she has had two records of six months each).

My mother wants to go to France for one month to visit my brother and then come back to Canada. The question is, after staying for almost two years in Canada as a tourist (with a tourist visa and two Visitor Records), will she be able to enter Canada again one month after leaving or should she wait longer before coming back to avoid any problems with immigration?

If this information is helpful, I am a Permanent Resident in Canada, my mother is from North Africa, and she is vaccinated.

Comment: Borders are opening up again, the need for an extended stay as a visitor is vanishing. What is her home country and are its borders open? When does her visitor record status expire? I suspect that her chances of being readmitted to Canada as a visitor just one month after exiting following a very lengthy stay are slim to none, and that she will likely need to spend a period of say at least 6 months out of Canada before she can hope to return. It may help you get better answers if you provided more information about her situation and why she wants to return

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Traveller. She is 60+ years old and divorced and has no close family in her home country. Before covid she usually spendt 6 months in canada and 6 months abroad. She wants to return because she(and myself) is affraid that the border in her home country closes again and she might end up alone there for a long time.

Comment: Has you considered applying for a super visa https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/parent-grandparent-super-visa/about.html It has to be done outside Canada. Sounds like your mum would have a hard time convincing an immigration officer that she has ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take her back to her home country if she tries to enter as an ordinary visitor again without a long gap